# How Can I Use A Comma Within A System() Shell Script In C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an app that will let users find processes that are taking up to much memory. I am doing this with the following code:

system("tasklist /fi "status eq not responding"");

My compiler isn't liking where I put the commas in.

This is the cmd command (or shell script, whatever) that I am trying to execute: tasklist /fi "status eq not responding".

Where should I put the commas?

Comment: A comma is `,`, I think you are talking about double quotes `"` here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly quote the command line within `system` call like:

```
system("/bin/echo \"a, b, c\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a "quote" not a comma. And if you want to insert a quote within a string you need to escape it with the escape character `\`
Like this:

```
system("tasklist /fi \"status eq not responding\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use \ as a Escape character before ", such like

system("tasklist /fi \"status eq not responding\"");